# how call forwading application works

Tags: c#, .net, gsm, at-command, telephony

How applications like twillo.com, ringcentral.com, talkroute.com works in background. Consider scenario i have call center number A and call center executive number B, C, E. If my customer Sam call on A, same call will be forwarded to B, C, E whoever attends call first will answer the call.  Now call is active between sam and executive B. Now if another customer jain call same procedure will repeat.

How can i achieve above work, i have simcom module and know how to handle calls using c# commands. Is there any network dependency because multiple calls are active at a time which i am not able to figure out, how it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about calls incoming from the public network to a business of other organisation, then the interface between the public network and the call centre is different than for a normal home or single line into a business.

Effectively, the business has its own private telephone exchange with a 'trunk' connection into the public network. This private exchange can be an on premise PABX or more sophisticated call centre system, or even a cloud hosted VoIP solution.

The connection and protocol between this private exchange and the public network can either be a traditional telephony protocol specially designed to support a network of PABX's, such as IETF QSig, or a VoIP based signalling system like SIP. In either case there will generally be some limit on the number of calls to and from the business, either because of the number of dedicated connections or the capacity of the IP connectivity or of the private exchange itself.

If you want to build an on premise solution yourself, then the open source Asterix solution would be good to take a look at:

- http://www.asterisk.org/get-started/applications/call-center